# Problems returning hashtable

Tags: powershell

So if I have the following code:

```
function DoSomething {
  $site = "Something"
  $app = "else"
  $app
  return @{"site" = $($site); "app" = $($app)}
}

$siteInfo = DoSomething
$siteInfo["site"]
```

Why doesn't $siteInfo["site"] return "Something"?

I can state just....

```
$siteInfo
```

And it will return

```
else

Key: site
Value: Something
Name: site

Key: app
Value: else
Name: app
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `$siteInfo["site"]` does return `Something` for me.

Comment: for me as well, powershell version?

Comment: Ok I have some more info.  I added just a simple call on a variable ($app) above in my function code.  What was occuring was that the value from $app and the hashtable was returned to the variable that called the function.  So if I did a ($siteInfo | fl) it would show both "else" and then the two key/values.  Why is that?

Comment: It seems that since you have `$app` all by itself on one line that you would like to print something to screen in the function itself but not return it to the caller. You can do this using the `Out-Host` or `Write-Host` cmdlets which will display the object, but not commit it to the pipeline. For example: `Write-Host $app` or `$app | Out-Host`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In PowerShell, functions return any and every value that is returned by each line in the function; an explicit `return` statement is not needed.

The `String.IndexOf()` method returns an integer value, so in this example, `DoSomething` returns '2' and the hashtable as array of objects as seen with `.GetType()`.

```
function DoSomething {
  $site = "Something"
  $app = "else"
  $app.IndexOf('s')
  return @{"site" = $($site); "app" = $($app)}
}

$siteInfo = DoSomething
$siteInfo.GetType()
```

The following example shows 3 ways to block unwanted output:

```
function DoSomething {
  $site = "Something"
  $app = "else"

  $null = $app.IndexOf('s')   # 1
  [void]$app.IndexOf('s')     # 2
  $app.IndexOf('s')| Out-Null # 3

  # Note: return is not needed.
  @{"site" = $($site); "app" = $($app)}
}

$siteInfo = DoSomething
$siteInfo['site']
```

Here is an example of how to wrap multiple statements in a ScriptBlock to capture unwanted output:

```
function DoSomething {
    # The Dot-operator '.' executes the ScriptBlock in the current scope.
    $null = .{
        $site = "Something"
        $app = "else"

        $app
    }

    @{"site" = $($site); "app" = $($app)}
}

DoSomething
```

Comment: @Thanks Rynant - In this example, isn't there a better way to manage return values.  Its very common to set variables, but to have to go back and block every possible return value from being returned turns a few line function into an ugly mess.  Could you filter I.E.> FunctionName | $_.<something here> to get to a return value?

Comment: @pghtech - In practice, I haven't found that there aren't many times that I need to explicitly block a return value since I am usually using the return value or there is no return value. Though I don't know if I've seen it in practice, I suppose you could wrap everything with `$null = .{ <# function contents #> }, but I would rather use `Out-Null` and the like when necessary.

Comment: Seriously, why ? Almost smashed my laptop trying to make some *** functions !

Comment: Why extra `$()` are used for `$site` and `$app`?

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 It's probably not needed. I was just modifying the code in the question.

Answer (score 2):

@Rynant VERY helpful post, thank you for providing examples on hiding function output!

My proposed solution:

```
function DoSomething ($a,$b){
  @{"site" = $($a); "app" = $($b)}
}

$c = DoSomething $Site $App
```